# Does atmospherejs provide any APIs?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Does [atmospherejs](https://atmospherejs.com/) provide any APIs to list and search **Meteor** packages. I would like to search and list meteor packages through an app.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Having in consideration that the Meteor ecosystem is growing, at this stage, this is not a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get complete list of packages at Home directory

```
~/.meteor/package-metadata/v1.1
```

in ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Now Atmospherejs have a simple REST API that gives access to the package metadata. To find metadata for a set of packages, make a query like:

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json" https://atmospherejs.com/a/packages/findByNames?names=iron:router,percolate:synced-cron
```

To get the entire package list:

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json" https://atmospherejs.com/a/packages
```

I found this [here](https://atmospherejs.com/i/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Send an email to the agency http://percolatestudio.com/ , they are the one who created http://www.atmospherejs.com

You can also check Meteor source code, you don't need to auth to download packages. So maybe there is a way of doing this.

I recommend to contact Percolate Studio. Your app might require more server to handle the demand.