# atmospherejs.com : Result search sorted by number of downloads

Tags: sorting, meteor, atmosphere.js

I am using atmospherejs.com for searching package but unfortunately it does not provide any criteria to sort the result : for example If I want to sort by number of downloads.

Is there anyway to get the result of a query sorted by some criteria : number of downloads, rating, new packages etc.

Thanks

Comment: http://ww2.meteor.com/spreadjs/linto

Comment: there are also other ways to get this done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057578/does-atmospherejs-provide-any-apis

Comment: Thanks @ChristianFritz It will help. Obviously, It should be done like that, because it is not possible to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can use the atmosphere API to get to the raw data and then filter and sort:

```
# get raw data
curl --header "Accept: application/json" https://atmospherejs.com/a/packages > /tmp/all.json

# process the json array in whatever way you want, for instance here
# only consider packages starting with an "f", then sort by installs per year
node -e "x = require('/tmp/all.json'); \
   console.log(x.filter(function(a) { return a.name[0] == 'f'; })\
     .sort(function(a,b) { return a['installs-per-year'] < b['installs-per-year']; }));"
```